# Vuejs v-for loop breaks column layout

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I have a `v-for` loop as seen below, which after an axios request will build my display of tracks for an artist.

```
<div class="item" v-for="i in Math.ceil(tracks.length / 5)">
    ....
</div>
<div class="item">
    ....
</div>
```

Now when I remove the `v-for` this is what the page looks like

[image]

However when I add in the v-for it looks like this:

[image]

Is there a reason they don't sit side by side any more, do I need to prevent this block from running until the tracks are downloaded? I am not sure.

Suggestions appreciated

Entire contents of the item divs:

```
<div class="item">
    <div class="img-box-horizontal music-img-box h-g-bg h-d-shadow">
        <div class="img-box img-box-sm box-rounded-sm">
            <img src="/assets/images/hot-song/hot-1.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="des">
            <h6 class="title"><a href="#">The Separation</a></h6>
            <p class="sub-title"><a href="#">Rachel Platten</a></p>
        </div>
        <div class="hover-state d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
            <span class="pointer play-btn-dark box-rounded-sm"><i class="play-icon"></i></span>
            <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
                <span class="adonis-icon text-light pointer mr-2 icon-2x"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1"><use xlink:href="#icon-heart-blank"></use></svg></span>
                <span class="pointer dropdown-menu-toggle"><span class="icon-dot-nav-horizontal text-light"></span></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="img-box-horizontal music-img-box h-g-bg h-d-shadow">
        <div class="img-box img-box-sm box-rounded-sm">
            <img src="/assets/images/hot-song/hot-2.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="des">
            <h6 class="title"><a href="#">Country girl shake it for me</a></h6>
            <p class="sub-title"><a href="#">Bing Crosby</a></p>
        </div>
        <div class="hover-state d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
            <span class="pointer play-btn-dark box-rounded-sm"><i class="play-icon"></i></span>
            <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
                <span class="adonis-icon text-light pointer mr-2 icon-2x"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1"><use xlink:href="#icon-heart-blank"></use></svg></span>
                <span class="pointer dropdown-menu-toggle"><span class="icon-dot-nav-horizontal text-light"></span></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="img-box-horizontal music-img-box h-g-bg h-d-shadow">
        <div class="img-box img-box-sm box-rounded-sm">
            <img src="/assets/images/hot-song/hot-3.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="des">
            <h6 class="title"><a href="#">Stirring of a fool</a></h6>
            <p class="sub-title"><a href="#">Rachel Platten</a></p>
        </div>
        <div class="hover-state d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
            <span class="pointer play-btn-dark box-rounded-sm"><i class="play-icon"></i></span>
            <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
                <span class="adonis-icon text-light pointer mr-2 icon-2x"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1"><use xlink:href="#icon-heart-blank"></use></svg></span>
                <span class="pointer dropdown-menu-toggle"><span class="icon-dot-nav-horizontal text-light"></span></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="img-box-horizontal music-img-box h-g-bg h-d-shadow">
        <div class="img-box img-box-sm box-rounded-sm">
            <img src="/assets/images/hot-song/hot-4.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="des">
            <h6 class="title"><a href="#">Nothings into Somethings</a></h6>
            <p class="sub-title"><a href="#">Rachel Platten</a></p>
        </div>
        <div class="hover-state d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
            <span class="pointer play-btn-dark box-rounded-sm"><i class="play-icon"></i></span>
            <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
                <span class="adonis-icon text-light pointer mr-2 icon-2x"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1"><use xlink:href="#icon-heart-blank"></use></svg></span>
                <span class="pointer dropdown-menu-toggle"><span class="icon-dot-nav-horizontal text-light"></span></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="img-box-horizontal music-img-box h-g-bg h-d-shadow">
        <div class="img-box img-box-sm box-rounded-sm">
            <img src="/assets/images/hot-song/hot-5.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="des">
            <h6 class="title"><a href="#">Let You Down</a></h6>
            <p class="sub-title"><a href="#">Rachel Platten</a></p>
        </div>
        <div class="hover-state d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
            <span class="pointer play-btn-dark box-rounded-sm"><i class="play-icon"></i></span>
            <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
                <span class="adonis-icon text-light pointer mr-2 icon-2x"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1"><use xlink:href="#icon-heart-blank"></use></svg></span>
                <span class="pointer dropdown-menu-toggle"><span class="icon-dot-nav-horizontal text-light"></span></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This remains the same for both before and after adding the `v-for`

Comment: In case this is a common error, make sure that your .item is indeed the item you need to repeat, the element you add the v-for to is the item that's going to be repeated and not only the inner html. Can you share the html of both screenshots, most likely this will have to do with html structure.

Comment: Added that at the bottom

Comment: All I change is that `v-for` line

Comment: There you go, this is a common mistake, try putting your v-for on your .img-box-horizontal element and not on .item

Comment: but the .item is what creates the coloumns every 5 items, which is what I am trying to achieve

Comment: Hmm can you share your uncompiled html with vue.js?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/d8JCmQe0

Comment: Ok I tested this markup and all seems fine, the item is repeated just fine, have you compared the normal html vs the compiled with vue.js one against the other? Sometimes is a simple extra div. If your html is exactly the same when compiled the styles should be the same.

Comment: Yeah they look the same to me, let me check again

Comment: Same issue, might just use a table instead

Comment: BTW make sure your owl-carousel is instantiated after vue.js has compiled the html, that could be an issue also.

Answer (score 0):

You using need v-for in

```html
//example 1
<ul>
  <li v-for="(item,index) in items">{item.name}</li>
</ul>

//example 2
<div class="item">
  <acticle v-for="(item,index) in items">
      <h2>{item.name}</h2>
      <span>date:{item.date}</span>
  </acticle>
</div>
```